# Is there any way or addon to facilitate the attachment/alignment of armor to a model?

Tags: modeling, mesh, workflow

I am trying to fit this armor into the model's arm, but I just can't get it too tightly firm around the arm, I know it fits, the armor piece and the model came in the same size, however, I just can't make it work.

I have tried scaling up the armor piece, but it just won't fit correctly, can anyone tell me if there is a better way to do this?

here is a reference image of how its supposed to look:

[image: reference armor]

here is my attempt:

[image]

[image]

[image]

armor file:

[image]

problems related to the first answer
[image]

[image]

Comment: I am not sure how to do that, the image that shows up nicely is from Google, I made the link reference the same way i did for the google image for my images, but it won't show up as it should, I don't know how to make it like the image above.

Comment: thanks! I have rearranged more images, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Juding by your model, rough scaling should work but since the scale has already been altered, the best methods you have are :-

> 1. Using **Shrinkwrap**:- Delete the outer faces and use the shrinkwrap modifier to stick to the faces to the main model's mesh directly or use a lattice. Then add a solidify modifier to give it some thickness
> 2. Retopologizing:-
>      [image]
>
> Turn on snapping and change the mode to face and then snap the individual faces/verts on the main mesh and use solidify to give it some thickness.

Comment: it didn't work.

I deleted the faces, wrapped the model onto the arm, and solidified it to give it some thickness, but it's not working properly.

ok, the model is sorta popping out but it is completely destroyed.

I...eh...what e_o????????

it took me a few hours and tutorials to understand what you were trying to suggest in the first option, the second one seems even more daunting, I don't know what to do.

here is the image of what I am talking about.
 ![valid XHTML][ https://imgur.com/a/22xPf]

Comment: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com use this to add your blendfile to the question. You can also add Gif images to your question. Your image link is dead.

Comment: ok, I added the blender file and the problematic pictures to the question, however, I don't know how to add gif images or images to my comments here, it says to write "![valid XHTML]", and then put the link to the image in between brackets, but it didn't work.


hope the problem is easier to approach now.